I can't display FastAPI StreamingResponse when receiving a chunk
Im trying to display a a StreamingResponse that I received from my fastAPI. I get the response by sending an axios post request. I Succesfully get the response chunk by chunk but I don't seem to be able to console.log() the chunks everytimes they arrive
This is my post request :


async sendSelectedDocumentList(
    projectId: number,
    selectedDocuments: string[],
  ) {
    return await axios.post(
      `/api/projects/${projectId}/thematiques/answer`,
      {
        document_names: selectedDocuments,
      },
      {
        params: { user_id: this.userId },
      },
    );
  }



I can see that I receive the anwser chunk by chunk in the network :


I finally succeeded by transforming my axios post request into a post request uising fertch API. I then used the getReader() method on the response.body :


async sendSelectedDocumentList(
    projectId: number,
    selectedDocuments: string[],
  ) {
    const data = {
      document_names: selectedDocuments,
    };
    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
      const response = await fetch(
        `/api/projects/${projectId}/thematiques/answer?user_id=${this.userId}`,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        },
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const reader = response.body?.getReader();

      if (reader) {
        while (true) {
          const { done, value } = await reader.read();
          if (done) break;
          console.log('Chunk:', new TextDecoder().decode(value));
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error('Response body is null or undefined');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }



